# Trouble clearing text field with .clear() *JAVA* *ANDROID*

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, appium

Hey im trying to clear a text field that my program previously sent text to by using these two lines here:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']")).click();`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']")).clear();`

But it only clears 2 out of 5 letters that need to cleared. How do i make it so it can clear all of the text at once?

Comment: I've seen similar posts to this in the past, and one offered solution that apparently works, though clunky, is to sendkeys backspace characters until the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` executor to clear the field if `clear()` is not working.

```
WebElement elementField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '';", elementField);
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  I have seen other posts saying that javascript is only available in Appium for "mobile:" commands.

Comment: @BillHileman - yep it will work for webapp or webview and not for native apps.

Comment: Since the locator is for a native app and not a webview, it wouldn't work, then.

Comment: Either way, the original poster has provided no feedback to either this answer or my other comment to his original post, apparently he's abandoned his own question or solved it and likewise provided no follow-up.